# Rowcolor on a multirow tabular in LaTeX

Tags: latex, colors, pdflatex, multirow

So I tried learning LaTeX last night, and I trying to get this template for school assignments done ASAP.  Part of that requires building a table.  I want to use multirow, but need the multirows, that are acting like headings, to be colored gray.  This is what I created so far from the almighty Google.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|p{5cm}|p{2.5cm}|l|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray} 
Stage & Aim & Procedure & Materials & Focus & Time \\ 
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray} 
\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{Engage} \\
\hline
Row 0 & Row 1 & Row 2 & Row 3 & Row 4 & Row 5 \\
%\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray} \multicolumn{6}{|l|}{Study} \\
\hline
Row 0 & Row 1 & Row 2 & Row 3 & Row 4 & Row 5 \\
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray} 
\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{Activate} \\
\hline
Row 0 & Row 1 & Row 2 & Row 3 & Row 4 & Row 5 \\
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray} 
\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{Conclusion} \\
\hline
Row 0 & Row 1 & Row 2 & Row 3 & Row 4 & Row 5 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work with pdflatex version 1.4.0 on Debian GNU/Linux 5.0.4 (lenny) I have in a VM.  Instead of doing it correctly, it ends up looking like [this](http://drop.io/ojyo1f6/asset/pdflatex-capture-png), where the first cell of the row after the multirow is blacked-out garbage.

Comment: I think this question should be moved to tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: At the time I do not think the Tex SE existed, but I could be wrong.  I did start using that subsequently.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|p{5cm}|p{2.5cm}|l|l|}

\hline
Stage & Aim & Procedure & Materials & Focus & Time \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|>{\columncolor[gray]{.8}}l|}{Engage} \\ 
\hline
Row 0 & Row 1 & Row 2 & Row 3 & Row 4 & Row 5 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|>{\columncolor[gray]{.8}}l|}{Study} \\ 
\hline
Row 0 & Row 1 & Row 2 & Row 3 & Row 4 & Row 5 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|>{\columncolor[gray]{.8}}l|}{Activate} \\ 
\hline
Row 0 & Row 1 & Row 2 & Row 3 & Row 4 & Row 5 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|>{\columncolor[gray]{.8}}l|}{Conclusion} \\ 
\hline
Row 0 & Row 1 & Row 2 & Row 3 & Row 4 & Row 5 \\
\hline

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Yes, `>{...}` is the command to place your `\columncolor` in (must be in it!). Also see 4.1 from [this PDF](https://web.archive.org/web/20100214195828/http://www.vision.ime.usp.br/~jmena/misc/latex/tables_with_latex.pdf).

Comment: You, sir, are my hero for the day.  Do you need `>` to embed that command or something?  Oh LaTeX, I wish I understood you better!

Comment: @BartKiers Link to pdf seems to be dead. Any chance for an update? :)

Comment: @radek, fixed the link.